# Let the incircle touch $AB$ and $AC$ at $F$ and $E$. Let $C \cap FE=L$ and $BI \cap EF= N$. Show that $B,L,N,C$ is cyclic.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with I as the incentre and let the incircle touch $AB$ and $AC$ at $F$ and $E$ . Let $C\cap FE=L$ and $BI\cap EF= N$ . Show that $B,L,N,C$ is cyclic.

[image]

Now, I haven't got any significant progress but here's my observations :

- $BLNC$ is cyclic , lying on the circle with diameter $ BC$
- $FLIB$ and $NIEC$ are cyclic too .

I think this question is easily bashable but I want to get a synthetic proof.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Knowing how ho prove that $FLIB$ and $NIEC$ are cyclic you're more that a half way solved it.

You need to prove $\angle LBN=\angle LCN$ (then $BLNC$ is cyclic).
But $\angle LBI=\angle LFI$ since $BFLI$ is cyclic,
similarly $\angle ICN=\angle IEN$ since $NIEC$ is cyclic.

So you need to prove $\angle IFE=\angle IEF$ but it's true since $\triangle IEF$ is isosceles -- $IF=IE$ are innerradii.

Comment: wait , I am so sorry I just observed that FLIB and NIEC are cyclic

Answer (score 1):

*Claim.* $\angle BLI=90$

*Proof of claim.* Its enough to show $BFLI$ is cyclic where $D=\odot(I)\cap BC$. For this, note that
$$\angle LDB=\pi - \angle LDC=\pi - \angle LEC=\angle AEF=\angle AFE$$Thus, $BFLI$ is cyclic. This completes the proof of claim.

Similarly, we get, $\angle BLC=90=\angle BNC$ so $BLNC$ is cyclic with $BC$ as diameter.

Comment: @Shubhangi Its Iran TST 2009/ 9...Anyway, lemme write a better answer...

Comment: yeah I got it on net..

Comment: @Shubhangi Okay so I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Anand ...